# Is there a way to add an empty parameter to the end of a RestSharp POST request?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to replicate a POST request that has an empty parameter at the end of the request body like this:

`param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&`

With RestSharp, I can't add a parameter with an empty key. Is there a way to get around this?